# openGL fixed function pipeline - scale texture intensity beyond 1.0

Tags: opengl, texturing

is there a way other than multitexturing or multipass rendering to scale a texture's intensity above factor 1.0 using the fixed function pipeline?

it can be achived with multipass rendering. for example factor 1.5 can be achieved by rendering the texture at full intensity once and then with color(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0) a second time using additive blending.

but is there also a way to achieve this with a single pass and without multitexturing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using either an OpenGL 3.0 or OpenGL ES library. I think you could do something like this, though I'm not sure how supported it is.

This should be a bit more supported than my original answer, but you're stuck with using 1.5 as the modulation value.

```
// Setup...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1);

// Combine: Result.rgb = Texture + Texture - 0.5
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_ADD_SIGNED);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE1_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);

// Combine: Result.a = Texture
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_ALPHA, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
```

If you can do it using shaders, you'd be much better off:

```
//Fragment shader
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float blend;
varying vec2 texcoord;
void main()
{
   vec4 texel0 = texture2D(texture, texcoord);
   texel0 *= blend;
   gl_FragColor = texel;
}
```

Comment: this looks great! is there any way to take the factor (1.5) through some of the vertex atributes? so that i can have different intensity factory for different polygons without having to issue single draw calls for each? I'm on openGL ES 1.5, shaders are not available

Comment: @Mat there is no such thing as OpenGL ES 1.5, only ES 1.1 and ES 2.0 exist.

Comment: my bad, i meant openGL ES 1.1 of course. the openGL reference of glTexEnv http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml states that color values are clamped to [0,1] - is it still possible somehow?

Comment: OpenGL texture combiners don't have access to the vertex values. It's an understandable mistake confusing OpenGL ES 1.1 with OpenGL 1.5; the former is derived from the latter. If you have to use OpenGL ES 1.1, then that means you're using fixed function hardware. It isn't programmable in the way that you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GL_RGB_SCALE` and `GL_ALPHA_SCALE` properties of the texture environment to apply a 2× or 4× scale factor, but this requires you to use the `GL_COMBINE` texture environment mode instead of the predefined modes. To get your 1.5 scale factor, you’d set `GL_RGB_SCALE` to 2.0 and set a color of {0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1.0}. Note that the texture environment for each texture unit still clamps to [0, 1], so if you need this type of scaling, you should apply the scale on the last texture unit to avoid any clipping.